# javascript for using textbox to pull up specific pictures

Tags: javascript, image, video, textbox

I'm a teacher and on the hunt for a simple javascript for my website. I know only basics, but this one is a bit above my head...

Is there a way where a child can type in a textbox, and a picture appears above it? For example,

1. type in a text box, e.g. "dog"
2. and upon clicking on the text box, a picture of a dog pops up above it

I have many pictures and videos in .png and .mp4 format (cat.png, dog.png, man.png, dog.mp4, etc) and I just want the child to be able type in any word from the list and have either a picture or video clip pop up above it.

Is it feasible? If so, is it possible to have 20 textboxes side by side, so the child can type in a word in each box (making a sentence), and each text box will generate pictures or video clips above each box?

(I have about 500 pictures and video clips in my hosting server, ready for access, just need a script of some kind (really simple, basic) to make them pop up in my website when the word for it is typed in).

Any input will be so much appreciated.

Comment: hi susan, stackoverflow is mainly for clarifying developer doubts with code and logics... your requirement looks like u need a new project

Comment: Appreciate your initiative, since this is for students education i wish to contribute at no cost.

Comment: thanks for explaining how this forum works, Varun, I have a javascripot that I put together which worked, but it seems to be a very long way to go about it, especially for around 500 pictures/words... there should be some kind of shortcut script for it, just for 20 text boxes (to make a sentence)... Here is the javascript below: